# How to differentiate drop down value and selected value from drop down using angular2-multiselect?

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, multi-select

I have one requirement where I have a multi select drop down and the values inside the drop down having "Code - Name". When I select from drop down then it should display only "Code". I am using angular2-multiselect in my Angular2 application.
Please help.

```
<angular2-multiselect 
    [data]="projectList" 
    [(ngModel)]="selectedProject" 
    [settings]="projectSettings" 
    (onSelect)="update($event)" 
    (onDeSelect)="update($event)" 
    (onSelectAll)="update($event)" 
    (onDeSelectAll)="update($event)"> 
</angular2-multiselect>
```

Comment: Will you please post some code?

Comment: <angular2-multiselect
            [data]="projectList"
            [(ngModel)]="selectedProject"
            [settings]="projectSettings"
            (onSelect)="update($event)"
            (onDeSelect)="update($event)"
            (onSelectAll)="update($event)"
            (onDeSelectAll)="update($event)">
          </angular2-multiselect>

Answer (score 1):

in your component file there you have to mention it as below

this.settings = {
      singleSelection: true,
      text: "Select Categories",
      selectAllText: 'Select All',
      unSelectAllText: 'UnSelect All',
      enableSearchFilter: true,
      badgeShowLimit: 3,
      labelKey: 'code',
      addNewItemOnFilter: true
    };
in ngOnInit()and 
 public settings={};(empty array )as a class variable
"lableKey " property will show in select